# Import a class from a hierarchy of packages

Tags: java, package

If there's a hierarchy of packages(i.e `pckg1.pckg2.pckg3`) and each of them has a same class(i.e Abc), then how do i import the class Abc from pckg1 ?

Is the statement  `import pckg1.pckg2.pckg3.Abc` ambiguous as `Abc` is present in all the three packages.

Comment: if you want to import from `pckg1`, just go `import pckg1.Abc;`

Comment: You're specifying the package. Why would it be ambiguous? Btw, there's no hierarchal relationship between packages.

Comment: Just in case your question's scope is being misunderstood... are you asking about importing class pkcg1.pckg2.pckg3.Abc at the same time as you are importing pkcg1.Abc in a single class? Or are you asking about just importing pkcg1.pckg2.pckg3.Abc? (I believe that the second one is both what you meant and what most answers currently assume.)

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as a package hierarchy actually.

`pckg1.pckg2` knows nothing about and inherits nothing from `pckg1`. Indeed, `pckg1.pckg2` can exist without there even being a `pckg1`. It's basically just a naming convention to help logically order things.

`pckg1.pckg2.pckg3.Abc` is therefore not ambiguous. It will come from the package that you currently consider the lowest in the hierarchy, `pckg3`.

<sub>That said, there is no such thing as `pckg3`. There is `pckg1`, `pckg1.pckg2` and `pckg1.pckg2.pckg3` but they could just as easily be called `cat`, `banana` and `magic`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

`import pckg1.pckg2.pckg3.Abc` is not ambiguous. It refer to specific class. In this case `Abc` from `pckg1.pckg2.pckg3` package.

In java there is no package hierarchy. It is only look like `pckg1.pckg2` and `pckg1.pckg2.pckg3`are related, but in fact there are no relation between them (except file structure where `.class` files are stored, but it is not part of language).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pckg1.Abc;
```

Look packages as windows folders.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you would:

```
import pckg1.Abc;
```

But I would also do the full package path when defining variables to avoid ambiguity.  For example:

```
pckg1.Abc abc = new pckg1.Abc();
```